# Missing property sources in Spring Cloud Config Server with S3 Backend

Tags: spring, amazon-s3, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

We are trying to migrate our Spring Cloud Config Server from a Git Backend to S3.

With git when we want to get config for the service `my-service` and profile `development` we hit

`https://my-config-server/my-service/development`

and this returns something like

```
{
    "name": "my-service",
    "profiles": [
        "development"
    ],
    "label": null,
    "version": "fgdfgdfg",
    "state": null,
    "propertySources": [
        {
            "name": "https://bitbucket.org/company/config-repo.git/my-service-development.yml",
            "source": {
                [properties]
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "https://bitbucket.org/company/config-repo.git/application-development.yml",
            "source": {
                [properties]
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "https://bitbucket.org/company/config-repo.git/my-service.yml",
            "source": {
                [properties]
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "https://bitbucket.org/company/config-repo.git/application.yml",
            "source": {
                [properties]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

And we have the files `my-service-development.yml`, `application-development.yml`, `my-service.yml` and `application.yml` so that properties in the more specific ones override properties in the more general ones.
Eg we can set a property in `my-service.yml` but override it for the development environment in `my-service-development.yml`. Likewise we can set common properties for an environment (such as database connections or messaging connections in `application-development.yml`.

However when we switch to S3 and hit the same URL we only get

```
{
    "name": "my-service",
    "profiles": [
        "development"
    ],
    "label": null,
    "version": "twtwert",
    "state": null,
    "propertySources": [
        {
            "name": "s3:my-service-development",
            "source": {
                [properties]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

ie we only get the most specific property source and not the others.

Is there something we are missing or is this a bug in the S3 implementation?

We are using spring boot 2.5.4, spring cloud 2020.0.3 and spring-cloud-aws 2.3.2